# Is it okay to use complex control flow in tf.function?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have the following Python function and I want to wrap it into `@tf.function` (originally the input arguments are numpy arrays, but for the sake of executing on GPU it's not a problem to convert them to TF tensors).

```
def reproject(before_frame, motion_vecs):
    reprojected_image = np.zeros((before_frame.shape[0], before_frame.shape[1], before_frame.shape[2]))
    for row_idx in range(before_frame.shape[0]):
        for col_idx in range(before_frame.shape[1]):
            for c_idx in range(before_frame.shape[2]):
                diff_u = int(round(
                         (before_frame.shape[1] * motion_vecs[row_idx][col_idx][0])
                     ))
                diff_v  = int(round(
                         (before_frame.shape[0] * motion_vecs[row_idx][col_idx][1])
                     ))
                before_pixel_position = (
                    row_idx + diff_v,
                    col_idx + diff_u
                )
                if before_pixel_position[0] < before_frame.shape[0] and before_pixel_position[1] < before_frame.shape[1] \
                    and before_pixel_position[0] > 0 and before_pixel_position[1] > 0:
                    reprojected_image[row_idx][col_idx][c_idx] = before_frame[
                        before_pixel_position[0]
                    ][
                        before_pixel_position[1]
                    ][c_idx]
    return reprojected_image
```

I can see that in Tensorflow tutorials people use `vectorized_map` or `map_fn` instead of loops, and `tf.cond` instead of the `if` operator. So is using these functions the only option for control flow, and if so, what are the reasons behind it?

Comment: There is absolutely no point in using @tf.function to wrap something that (apparently) only operates on numpy arrays.

Comment: @xdurch0, but if I want GPU execution, then I need the arguments to be TF tensors, don't I?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It's actually a big problem because `reprojected_image` is an `np.array` in this code. Even if the function inputs were tensors, the program would have to keep switching to CPU to fill the array (numpy does not support GPU computation). You also cannot use a tensor for `reprojected_image` because tensors do not support item assignment. You could use a `tf.Variable` but that will be extremely slow. However, newer TF versions support an experimental numpy API, maybe that is appropriate: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tf_numpy

Comment: On another note, the tutorials you are referring to may simply be outdated. Control flow was difficult in TF1, but is much simpler in TF2. In many cases, you _can_ now use loops, if-conditions etc. and wrap them in `@tf.function`. Finally, note that _graph execution_ (which is what `tf.function` does) and _GPU execution_ are different things. The latter does not require the former (and vice versa).